# PuTTY new line not working properly

Tags: ssh, putty

I have PuTTY hooked up to a serial port and am reading an output of an AVR.

I send print command like this:

```
printf("OCR1A: %d \n", OCR1A);
```

And PuTTY does go to the next line but does not reset the column. Shown here[image]

**How can I have PuTTY start the newline column at zero instead 1 + current cursor position?**

Comment: If the remote system is some flavor of Unix, an `stty` setting should fix that. I think it's `stty onlcr`.

Comment: @garyjohn i'm working with an AVR through serial tx and rx lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed a carriage return as well as a new line character.

```
printf("Hello world\r\n");
```

Comment: That doesn't even correctly answer your own question, which was how to get PuTTY to handle the `\n` as a newline with implicit carriage return (`\r`), and not how to change your code to make it match PuTTY's default behavior.

Answer (score 14):

Enable the ["Implicit CR in every LF"](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#i27) option.

Comment: Changing it to this gave me garbage charters. The USART communcation I don't think like it.

Comment: It's 2017, and like minicom, this only applies for the output, and just adds extra noise.

Comment: This didn't make any difference at all for me.

Answer (score 7):

Putty Doesn't transmit `\n`, regardless of option settings.

Using [Tera Term](https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/index.html.en) (open source, windows or linux), you can easily terminate transmissions with `\n`, `\n\r`, `\r` or `Auto`.

Comment: Cancel that; -1; Tera Term doesn't run in Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the PuTTY Configuration

Go to Terminal and mark this options:

- Implicit CR in every LF
- Implicit LF in every CR

[image: putty config]