# putty screen mess up with any command

Tags: putty

I'm new in this forum, I'm sorry if this question is a duplicate I couldn't find it. I have been trying to run a simple command like `tasklist` on a remote windows server and the terminal is printing a mess:

[image]

How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PuTTY new line not working properly](https://superuser.com/questions/654490/putty-new-line-not-working-properly)

Comment: I took another look at that post and it does look distinct from your issue, since yours happens with every command. In the Putty, can you check the following settings under Terminal: Implicit CR in every LF and Implicit LF in every CR.

Comment: I just tested enabling one by one and then both. With both  Implicit CR in every LF and Implicit LF in every CR, improved a lot the display. It keeps creating a new line for long rows though.